# How to check which elements are being targeted from .on with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-on

I am unsure which elements are being targeted within my `.on`

```
 $('.levelFour').on('mouseover','> li',function(m){
```

I wonder, is there a way to display which elements are being targeted?

Comment: in your console ` $('.levelFour > li')`

Answer (score 0):

Inside an event handler, `this` will be bound to the element that the event fired on. To create a jQuery object from it, use `$(this)`.

Comment: return this will mean that i would have to hover over each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command in your browser console

```
$('.levelFour > li')
```

It will list all the elements which are targeted by the event handler at the point of execution. It will vary time to time depends on your dom structure.

Comment: As i suspected... Not quite what i was hoping for though. I must say its odd. As i know  it will look for the selector within `.levelFour` But how can `>` operator work without a parent to do the test against. I wonder how this is computed or worked out.

Comment: since your base is ` $('.levelFour')` it will look for children of `.levelFour`

Comment: i only want first decenents of .levelFour, hence `>`. So what you're saying is I can do `'> li'` as i have done and it will target the first set of children?

Comment: If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/MW6Cq/ you can find that the border is applied only to the direct children

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.levelFour').on('mouseover','> li',function(m){
//something
}).css("border","1px solid red");
```

will change the border of element to red.
hope it helps.

Comment: This won't work as it will only target `.levelFour` as far as i'm aware?